# Updating embedded document property in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a document that looks like this:

```
{
    "_id": 3,
    "Slug": "slug",
    "Title": "title",
    "Authors": [
        {
            "Slug": "slug",
            "Name": "name"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to update all Authors.Name based on Authors.Slug.
I tried this but it didn't work:

```
.update({"Authors.Slug":"slug"}, {$set: {"Authors.Name":"zzz"}});
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: "{ "_id" : 3, "Slug" : "slug", "Title" : "title", "Authors" : [ "Slug" : "slug", "Name" : "name"] }" is not a valid document. If you provide example data then provide *working* example data.

Comment: I missed some curly braces. it's a valid document now.

Comment: Dude, also your update does not work...do you want to waste our time?> db.foo.update({"Authors.Slug":"slug"}, {$set: {"Authors.Name":"zzz"}})
can't append to array using string field name [Name]

Comment: that's my question. I want to know why the update doesn't work

Comment: look at the "positional operator" and $elemMatch

Comment: the positional operator was what I needed. this is what works for the update:

.update({"Authors.Slug":"slug"}, {$set: {"Authors.$.Name":"zzz"}});

Answer (score 61, accepted):

```
.update(Authors:{$elemMatch:{Slug:"slug"}}, {$set: {'Authors.$.Name':"zzz"}});
```

Comment: You don't need to use elemMatch to do this. It's the "$" in the 2nd part that does the trick. See here: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating/#Updating-The%24positionaloperator

Comment: Not necessarily true. The query part must uniquely identify an array element for the positional operator and {Authors.Slug:"slug"} is not semantically equivalent to the $elemMatch version. The $elemMatch version does partial matching even if you have more than one field in the same element to match making it the superior method to do these things.

Comment: I know it's an old answer, but I am having trouble _really_ understanding the difference between queries made with $elemMatch and their "normal" equivalent (like above). What do you mean by "The $elemMatch version does partial matching even if you have more than one field in the same element to match" ?

Comment: @Merc : Say the elements in your array have fields "a" and fields "b" : arr:[{a:1, b:1}, {a:2, b:10}, ..]. In that case arr:{$elemMatch:{a:1}} would match the first element (the element has a field "a" with value 1) bit arr:{a:1} would not (the element is {a:1, b:1} and not {a:1}. In other words, without $elemMatch the entire element in the array should match rather than a specific set of fields.

Comment: @Merc you're very welcome. A more detailed explanation is in the documentation here : http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/elemMatch/

Comment: This page on the ["$" positional operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) has all the needed details.

Answer (score 2):

You can use update with array filters:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#positional-update-arrayfilters

Probably something like this:

```
yourcollection.update(
{},
{
    "$set": {
        "Authors.$[element].Name": "zzz"
    }
},
{
    "multi": true,
    "arrayFilters": [
         { "element.Slug": "slug" }
    ]
}
)
```

Ps.: **it will not work in Robo3T** as explained here: [Mongodb 3.6.0-rc3 array filters not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47225822/mongodb-3-6-0-rc3-array-filters-not-working)
However, you can try on a mongo shell with version >= 3.6.

Answer (score 0):

yes, Rock's solution is working, P.S Notes is really helpful when trying Robo31.. 
If we want to update all 
db.collection_name.update({}, {$set: {"Authors.$[].Name": "zzz"}})

If we want to update with matching object in an array 
db.collection_name.update({}, {$set: {"Authors.$[i].Name": "zzz"}}, {arrayFilters: [{"i.Slug": "slug"}]})

Ref: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1243