# How do I use elemMatch to find a value in the array and set it with a new value?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Hey I am trying to allow users to update their emails in an array. I want to update a specific email of theirs if they click on edit. I have the old value and the new value, I know I can do a pull and push but wanted to see if I can do it in a more efficient way with matching the value with the $elemMatch then $set it with the new value? I tried the positional operator but it does not work for just values in an array without a key relationship meaning fieldx: value x... here is my attempt, not sure how to go about it? Other directions are welcomed.

```
User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.signedCookies.userid,{
            emailList: { $elemMatch: {oldEmail, {$set: {req.body.updateEmail}}}}
        }, function(err, userX) {});
```

Comment: Have you tried something similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758339/updating-embedded-document-property-in-mongodb) ?

Comment: Yeah it does not work for me my problem is different because my array is just values, should I be adding a field for each value to keep it in a key pair like so email: value, email: value etc...

Answer (score 0):

The MongoDB syntax would be

```
> db.test.insert({userId: '1234', emailList: ['abc', 'def']})
> db.test.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("520eaade49177daf439a2ffa"), userId: '1234', "emailList" : [ "abc", "def" ] }
> db.test.update({userId: '1234', emailList: 'abc'}, {$set: {'emailList.$': 'ghi'}})
> db.test.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("520eaade49177daf439a2ffa"), userId: '1234', "emailList" : [ "ghi", "def" ] }
>
```

The Mongoose code would then be

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({userId: '1234', emailList: 'abc'}, {$set: {'emailList.$': 'ghi'}})
```

This will allow you to make the change in one query as opposed to a $pull and $push

Since you're searching an array of values and not an array of documents, you don't need $elemMatch.  You can just query the array directly and MongoDB knows to look inside it and match a value.

Comment: Yeah, how do I go about doing that because I am not sure how to work what you got up there in findByIdAndUpdate({_id: userCookie,
   emailList: oldEmail}, {$set: {'emailList.$': newEmail}

Comment: Yeah, I tried that it is not working... keeps giving me this error: { message: 'Cast to ObjectId failed for value "[object Object]" at path "_id"'
  name: 'CastError',
  type: 'ObjectId',
  value: { _id: 'userCookie', emailList: 'oldEmail' },
  path: '_id' }