# Updating only certain sub documents in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

Given a document as such

```
{
  _id: '123456',
  items: [{
     itemId: 'abcd',
     qty: 1
  }, {
     itemId: 'defg',
     qty: 3 
  }]
}
```

I want to *only* update certain items; for example, I only want to increment `itemId = 'abcd'` 's  quantity by `5`, such that the resulting doc would become

```
{
  _id: '123456',
  items: [{
     itemId: 'abcd',
     qty: 6
  }, {
     itemId: 'defg',
     qty: 3 
  }]
}
```

How do I do that?

Comment: the update command on the mongo shell should work : db.cols.update({"items.itemId":"abcd"},{$set:{"items.$.qty":5}}). you need to use the $ operator to update an element in an array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating embedded document property in Mongodb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758339/updating-embedded-document-property-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically there are 3 steps :

1. Select the `itemid` from items array where value is abcd
2. Use `$inc` property to increment
3. Use `$` operator (positional update) to specify that you want to

Increment the qty key from the document to be updated.

PFB final query :

```
db.schools.update({ 
    items.itemId: 'abcd'
},{
    $inc : { items.$.qty : 5 }
});
```

Comment: I thought the `$` operator would update *every* sub documents, but you are telling me that the database is smart enough to match an update only the matched subdocuments?

Comment: Yes so first argument to the update is the query using which we will filter out the documents first and then second argument is something which will tell what to update in those filtered documents..

Comment: Field update operators like $inc and $set do not update every sub document, they only modify specified field.

Comment: Yes adi, it will modify the particular field only.. not the entire document.