# Mongodb 3.6.0-rc3 array filters not working?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to use array filters in mongodb 3.6.0-rc3, exactly like in [doc example](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#update-all-array-elements-that-match-arrayfilters) but not getting any rows affected and no error.

Example is simplified. I know this can be done with $ as positional operator but I'm planing to use this feature for two level nested arrays.

```
db.getCollection('books').update({},
    {
        $set: { "authors.$[element].firstName": "Joe" }
    },
    {
        arrayFilters: [ { element: { "_id": ObjectId("some_id") } } ],
        multi: true
    })
```

Anyone tried this yet?

Answer (score 10):

Are you typing this in robomongo?  It looks like it! If so it won't work. Read my note on [Updating a Nested Array with MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23577123/updating-a-nested-array-with-mongodb) where I say this does not work in an "older shell" or anything based on it ( which robomongo is a shell based build ) because of the way the shell helper methods are currently implemented:

> **NOTE** Somewhat ironically, since this is specified in the "options" argument for `.update()` and like methods, the syntax is generally compatible with all recent release driver versions.
>
> However this is not true of the `mongo` shell, since the way the method is implemented there ( "ironically for backward compatibility" ) the `arrayFilters` argument is not recognized and removed by an internal method that parses the options in order to deliver "backward compatibility" with prior MongoDB server versions and a "legacy" `.update()` API call syntax.
>
> So if you want to use the command in the `mongo` shell or other "shell based" products ( notably Robo 3T ) you need a latest version from either the development branch or production release as of 3.6 or greater.

So if you want to "play with" the release candidate, either use the bundled `mongo` shell with that version or simply run your code through any standard driver.

Comment: Thanks @NeilLunn. I tried it first in Robo 3T 1.1.1 and got:

`No array filter found for identifier 'element' in path 'authors.$[element].firstName'`


then in MongoDB shell version v3.6.0-rc3:

`WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })`

Comment: Installed mongo following this tutorial: https://docs.mongodb.com/master/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

Comment: @SenadMehic English may be a problem here. **Will not work in RoboMongo**. Use the [`mongo`](https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/shell/client/) shell instead. See also [Update nested subdocuments in MongoDB with arrayFilters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47233482/2313887). And check `db.version()`, as you possibly updated a shell but not the server. Must be a 3.6 rc or a development release greater than 3.5.12

Comment: Thanks, this has solved my issue, but somehow this error pop'd up only few times in robo3T with the same query being ran for couple of times, remaining all times I saw `Updated 0 record(s)` or `Updated 1 record(s)` though nothing got updated via robo3T !!

Answer (score 2):

```
db.getCollection('books').update({},
    {
        $set: { "authors.$[element].firstName": "Joe" }
    },
    {
        arrayFilters: [ { "element._id": ObjectId("some_id") } ],
        multi: true
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

this BUG,just upgrade studio-3t version to 2018.6.1,use $ and arrayFilter OK.I try it in mongo4.0.4 and studio-3t